# What is the correct DateTime format in WebSQL to perform date comparison queries?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, datetime-format, web-sql

I have an existing table that stored all fields with `datetime` data types in the following format:

```
Tue Jun 09 2015 08:39:56 GMT-0300 (Atlantic Daylight Time)
```

This seems to be the wrong format to be used with HTML5's WebSQL databases.

How can I go from this format, to an acceptable format that I could query for records after / before / between a certain date and time?

Also, what would be the easiest way to replace each records? Select all, do the replacement via Javascript, then update all? Or is there a way to do it only with SQL (for WebSQL, that is)?

**Note**: The `datetime` data was originally populated with Javascript's `new Date()` object, and it was just passed directly (so essentially it invoked it's `toString()` method). Is there some other method that would store the data directly in the database in its acceptable format (for comparing dates)?

Comment: The format is independent of the value. It shows you a representation of the datetime value, in _your_ timezone. You can compare with whatever format is supported. `Y-m-d H:i:s` is probably supported, I would also expect the default toString of Date to be supported. Try it.

Comment: @Halcyon, you're correct - my bad for thinking it wasn't handling the Date.toString() format.

Comment: Self-closing the question now. (Not sure if this is the right approach or if I should just delete it).

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it :)